# copy/paste (hair) modifier properties (different files)

Tags: modifiers, particles, hair

Perhaps this is related to any modifier that has desired/tuned parameters....
I have played around with hair settings on a modified UV-sphere mesh in file-1, and now i'd like to migrate/save (copy/paste) all of these satisfactory settings onto a different mesh (separate scalp mesh of a character) in a different file.

In 3ds Max, there is a hair copy/paste and Save/Load preset.  Is there a modifier copy paste in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to File -> Append, browse to your previous file and open the Particle Settings folder to bring over the settings.  Just create a particle system in the new file and slot the settings in under it.

Comment: Is there a way to transfer the Particle Edit also?  It appears that my hair styling is not transferred.